# What is the default value for SSLRandomSeed directive?

Tags: apache, ssl

I can't find the default value for SSLRandomSeed directive from the following manual:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrandomseed

What is the default value for SSLRandomSeed directive?